# How to hide warning and show errors only in Stylelint linting result?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, stylelint

Stylelint has this option `"severity": "warning"` to changed errors to warnings. Is it possible to hide warnings from output temporarily? because I want to fix some errors and because of lots of warnings, it takes a long time to reach to error instances

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are looking for the `quiet` option which suppress "warnings"

https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/cli.js#L257-L260

> --quiet, -q
> Only register warnings for rules with an "error"-level severity (ignore
> "warning"-level).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a choice:

1. Turn off the rules [using `null`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#the-configuration-object).
2. Write [a custom formatter](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/formatters.md#writing-formatters) that does not display warnings.